# How to use the masterpage div tage in content placeholder pageload event?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

i am writing code like this **(master.master)**

```
<div id="Invoice" runat="server" visible="false">
                            <div class="quicklinks">
                                Quick Links</div>
                            <ul style="margin-top: 0px;">
                                <li style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;"><a href="cliFindInvoice.aspx?Customer=10">
                                    <img src="images/bull.png" />Invoice</a></li>
                                <li style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;"><a href="cliFindInvoice.aspx?Customer=20">
                                    <img src="images/bull.png" />Payments</a></li>
                                <li style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;"><a href="cliAddNewLineitem.aspx">
                                    <img src="images/bull.png" />Add new Line Item</a></li>
                                <li style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;"><a href="cliAccountType.aspx">
                                    <img src="images/bull.png" />Chat of Accounts</a></li>
                                <li style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;"><a href="cliViewCustomerInvoices.aspx">
                                    <img src="images/bull.png" />All Transactions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

i am click the button in content place holder  open the new page.that page load event div visible property is true.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ContentPlaceHolder myContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
        myContent.FindControl("Invoice").Visible = true;

    }
```

but it is not working pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`this.MasterPage.FindControl("yourdivid").visible=true;`

Answer (score 0):

If you add the MasterType directive to your content page like the example below, you will be able to reference the div directly in your code behind.

In content page:

```
<%@ Page  masterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"%>
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>
```

In code behind:

```
Master.Invoice.Visible = true;
```

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) for more information.